# Vertical align bar chart from chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I tried to align bar chart in the middle of div but somehow it's not working. 
Tried with this code below but it seems not working too:

**CSS:**

```css
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
flex:1;
```

See the jsfiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/lilpenguin/wc27x8d6/48/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because chart has a width size over your div.
Make a chart with `width:100%;` or `margin: 0 auto;`